# Determine memory used by asp.net cache in shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, shared-hosting

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829681/asp-net-cache-or-manual-caching/), I want to know if asp.net's system.web.caching.cache is good for me, or I should use database caching?

So, I need to know how much memory is being used by system.Web.caching.cache? 
But since I am using a shared hosting server, I can't use task manager.
Is there any way to determine how much memory is used by system.web.caching.cache using some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One fast way to see how many working memory your application use is to direct ask the garbage collection.

```
long bytes = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
txtMemoryUsed.Text = bytes.ToString();
```

and use this literal `<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtMemorysUsed" EnableViewState="false" />`

But you can get more details using the `PerformanceCounter`, for example you can get how many virtual memory the pools used by this code:

```
 var oPerfCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
oPerfCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
oPerfCounter.CounterName = "Virtual Bytes";
oPerfCounter.InstanceName = "aspnet_wp";
txtMemorysUsed.Text = "Virtual Bytes: " + oPerfCounter.RawValue + " bytes";
```

You can use all this parameters to get information's for your pool.

```
Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
Process(aspnet_wp)\% Processor Time
Process(aspnet_wp)\Private Bytes
Process(aspnet_wp)\Virtual Bytes
Process(aspnet_wp)\Handle Count
Microsoft® .NET CLR Exceptions\# Exceps thrown / sec
ASP.NET\Application Restarts
ASP.NET\Requests Rejected
ASP.NET\Worker Process Restarts (not applicable to IIS 6.0)
Memory\Available Mbytes
Web Service\Current Connections
Web Service\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec
```

for example, this parametres get the cpu load.

```
oPerfCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
oPerfCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
oPerfCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
txtOutPut.Text = "Current CPU Usage: " + oPerfCounter.NextValue() + "%";
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx

relative: [Monitoring ASP.NET application memory from within the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586544/monitoring-asp-net-application-memory-from-within-the-application)

I have test that on local iis and works.

Comment: Does GC gives me the memory used by just current Web application?

Comment: @Mahdi in a shared environment the pool is run many sites, your site is lives with other sites, except if you have ask for a "private" pool. (so its not just current web application, but is the pool). So you get the memory of your pool (including other sites that runs together)

Comment: My control panel is plesk, and it seems that every user has an application pool. (I can stop/start it or even limit CPU usage of my sites). So, is my application pool private?

Comment: @Mahdi tells you only your application.

Comment: @Mahdi Make many test local, and compare the results with the process monitor from sysinternals, to understand the numbers.

Comment: @Mahdi I think yes must be private ! Check on the plesk say that you have a distinct pool (with a check box on the general parameters of the site) (I also have plesk on servers and there is this option)

Comment: I think I have just start/stop/recycle option and CPU limiting option.

Comment: @Mahdi if you have this options, probably you have distinct pool to not affect others.